# VBA save as not working in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I'm hoping I am hoping some can help me

I am trying to use the below code to save files in Excel 2013 but I am getting the following error message:-

> Method 'SaveAs' object'__Workbook' failed

Can anyone advise?

```
Sub SaveFile()

Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Name As String

Set Sourcewb = ThisWorkbook
Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook
Name = Cells(2, 2).Value

FolderName = Sourcewb.Path & "\Files_with_graphs"
FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56

With Destwb
        .SaveAs FolderName _
        & "\" & Name & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        .Close False

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

You're using an invalid file format.

.xls is Excel 97-2003 format, for which you would want `-4143` not `56`

Seeing as you're working with the Excel object model you can just use the `xlFileFormat` enumeration which is also better for compatibility:

```
FileFormatNum = xlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal
```

[MSDN - xlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this, however when I make the amendment I get the following error message:-

Comment: That error is nothing to do with this code and should be listed as a new question. Also please mark as the answer if this solved the save issue.